# spread object and conditionaly modify one property ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have object as below

```
const myObject = {
      "Obj1" :[ {
         name:"test",
         down:"No"
         Up: "Yes",
        },
        { }, {}....
           
       ],
     "Obj2" :[ {}, {}......

           
       ],
     "Obj3" : [ {}, {}, {....
           
       ],
}
```

I want to clone above object and want to modified "Obj1" if name="test" then make it as Up to "Yes"

Basically I want to conditionally spread object property.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: I know we can do using `let updatedObj = {...myObj, modify property here }` but dont know how excately can be done here.. baiscally find and update property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the question is a bit unclear. Anyway,
if you want to conditionally update 'up' if 'name' === 'test' from a cloned object:

```js
import { cloneDeep } from lodash/fp;
// you can use also JSON stringify + JSON parse
// spread operator will only shallow copy your object

//clone it
const deepClonedObject = cloneDeep(myObject);

// update items accordingly to your needs
deepClonedObject.obj1 = deepClonedObject.obj1.map(item => (item.name === 'test'
  ? { ...item, up: 'Yes' }
  : item)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it combine `reduce` and `map`. `reduce` because it versatile and can return object instead array and `map` to update properties.

```js
const myObject = {
  Obj1: [
    {
      name:"test",
      down:"No",
      Up: "No",
    },
  ],
  Obj2: [
    {
      name:"test",
      down:"No",
      Up: "No",
    },
  ],
  Obj3: [
    {
      name:"test2",
      down:"No",
      Up: "No",
    },
  ],
};

const updatedObject = Object.keys(myObject).reduce((obj, key) => {
  return {
    ...obj,
    [key]: myObject[key].map((newObject) => {
      if (newObject.name === 'test') {
        newObject.Up = 'Yes';
      }

      return newObject;
    })
  };
}, {});

console.log(updatedObject);
```